# How to write algorithm for Sequencing n jobs on n machines?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I am just trying to write an algorithm.To Sequencing n jobs on n machines.
for ex:-

```
 job1->2s;
 job2->1s;
 job3->5s;
```

first we have to sort that job with time (desc)

```
 job3->5s;
 job1->1s;
 job2->2s;
```

Suppose we have 2 machines

```
machine1->job3
machine2->job2
```

job 2 will first finished wirte the next step should be

```
machine1->job3 => 5s
machine2->job2+job1(2s+1s) => 3s
```

And i want that total working for that machine1 
which is 5s it is the longest working machine right i want that answer.
How to write algorithm for this...
what i've done so far is sorting that objects in time order...
then i don't how to imporve this algorithm to work with n number of machines with n number of jobs..

thanks in advance

run.js

```
 var sorty = require('sorty');
    var njobs = [
        {
            jobname:"j1",
            time:42
        },
        {
            jobname:"j2",
            time:56
        },
        {
            jobname:"j3",
            time:78
        },
        {
            jobname:"j4",
            time:68
        },
        {
            jobname:"j5",
            time:43
        },
        {
            jobname:"j6",
            time:99
        },
        {
            jobname:"j7",
            time:88
        }
    ];
    var machines = 4;
    //sort desc with time
    var order = sorty([
        {name:'time',dir: 'desc',type:'number'}

    ],njobs);

    for(i=0;i<order.length;i++){
            console.log('job Name :'+order[i].jobname+' job Time to finish :'+order[i].time+' alloting machines to job');


    }
```

Comment: Are the jobs independent (can run in any order)?  Is the objective to minimize the idle time of the machines?

Comment: As it is currently formulated this question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19197836/algorithm-to-evenly-distribute-values-into-containers but if you allow for dynamic scheduling (i.e. when the values are more like workload hints than actual runtimes), other possibilities arise...

Comment: No  jobs should run Descending order of time.objective is find out which machine proccessing time is high

Comment: @danh could pls figured it out how to do this...

Comment: Question really needs an edit to explain objective and constraints.

Comment: @danh done some changes hope it will understand

Comment: I guess this can be modeled as assigning tasks to workers and requires and asynchronous workflow which can simply be implemented with promises. I would first group the jobs so that each group should have equal or close to equal workload and then a `promise.all` per group might be reasonable. Nice question though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example implementation in javascript of the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19198357/3297291) (linked to by user [BeyelerStudios](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3426025/beyelerstudios) in the comments.

- Sort jobs by time, starting with the highest
- Create a list of machines
- For each machine, store the total job time of all its jobs
- Loop through jobs, assign job to the machine that has the *lowest* total job time

As the linked answer states: this by no means guarantees you the perfect, best solution. Also, if we're talking thousands of jobs and machines, you'd want to optimize for performance... If you're working with data sets like the ones you provided in the question, the example implementation below might work for you.

```js
var njobs = [{
  jobname: "j1",
  time: 42
}, {
  jobname: "j2",
  time: 56
}, {
  jobname: "j3",
  time: 78
}, {
  jobname: "j4",
  time: 68
}, {
  jobname: "j5",
  time: 43
}, {
  jobname: "j6",
  time: 99
}, {
  jobname: "j7",
  time: 88
}];

var sorted = njobs.sort((a, b) => b.time - a.time);
var machines = Array(4).fill().map((m, i) => { return { id: i, value: 0, jobs: [] } });

sorted.forEach(job => {
  var minMachine = machines
    .slice(1)
    .reduce((res, cur) => res.value < cur.value ? res : cur, machines[0]);
  
  minMachine.jobs.push(job);
  minMachine.value += job.time;
});

console.log(machines.map(m => "Machine " + m.id + 
                         ", time: " + m.value + 
                         ", jobs: " + m.jobs.map(j => j.jobname).join(", ")));
```

(Note: for old-browser-support you might have to polyfill `Array#fill`)

Answer (score -1):

@user3297291 great implementation, but your technique only consider (n) number of jobs, but not (m) number of machines.

Here is another implementation which is capable to calculate for any number of Jobs (n) or Machines (m) where (n&m > 1). It validates the given data set and not only apply Johnson's rule but also uses CDS Algorithm to dig deep and calculate more complex alternatives with less possible makespan. Later you can export the entire timeline to excel or pdf format for further use.

The tool is completely free to use https://job-sequencing.appspot.com
Feel free to experiment!