# split array of objects into three seperate array based on a property

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, split, chunks

I have a array of objects with property of id and size. Sum of objects size equals to 78 and I want to split this objects by three array. But I want to split possibly equal sum of size (~ 78/3 +-).

I have a this array of objects,

```
[
 {'id': '1', 'size': '10'},
 {'id': '2', 'size': '4'},
 {'id': '3', 'size': '6'},
 {'id': '4', 'size': '21'},
 {'id': '5', 'size': '2'},
 {'id': '6', 'size': '1'},
 {'id': '7', 'size': '6'},
 {'id': '8', 'size': '7'},
 {'id': '9', 'size': '8'},
 {'id': '1', 'size': '13'}
]
```

And I want

```
[
 [
  {'id': '4', 'size': '21'},
  {'id': '2', 'size': '4'}, 
  {'id': '6', 'size': '1'},
 ],
 [
  {'id': '1', 'size': '13'},
  {'id': '1', 'size': '10'},
  {'id': '5', 'size': '2'},
 ],
 [
  {'id': '3', 'size': '6'}, 
  {'id': '9', 'size': '8'},
  {'id': '7', 'size': '6'},
  {'id': '8', 'size': '7'},
 ]
]
```

Comment: I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19197836/1270789) will be a pointer in the right direction. If you have a specific question after trying to implement one of the solutions in JavaScript, then we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an NP-complete problem so there is more then one solution. One approach I thought of is putting the bigger items first and then putting the smaller items where you have more space.

```js
let items = [
    {'id': '1', 'size': 10},
    {'id': '2', 'size': 4},
    {'id': '3', 'size': 6},
    {'id': '4', 'size': 21},
    {'id': '5', 'size': 2},
    {'id': '6', 'size': 1},
    {'id': '7', 'size': 6},
    {'id': '8', 'size': 7},
    {'id': '9', 'size': 8},
    {'id': '1', 'size': 13}
];
//sort the array by size in reverse order
items.sort((a, b)=> b.size - a.size);
//array of sums
let sums = [0,0,0];
//final array of 3 arrays
let arrays = [[],[],[]];
for (let item of items) {
    //get index of the smallest sum
    let index =  sums.indexOf(Math.min.apply(null,sums));
    //add current item size to corresponding sum
    sums[index] += item.size;
    //add item to corresponding array
    arrays[index].push(item);
}
console.log(arrays);
console.log(sums);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `while()` loop:

```js
var arr = [
 {'id': '1', 'size': '10'},
 {'id': '2', 'size': '4'},
 {'id': '3', 'size': '6'},
 {'id': '4', 'size': '21'},
 {'id': '5', 'size': '2'},
 {'id': '6', 'size': '1'},
 {'id': '7', 'size': '6'},
 {'id': '8', 'size': '7'},
 {'id': '9', 'size': '8'},
 {'id': '1', 'size': '13'}
];
var i=0, res = [], tempArr=[];
while(i<arr.length){
  if(i!==0 && i%3 === 0){
    res.push(tempArr);
    tempArr = [arr[i]];
  } else {
    tempArr.push(arr[i]);
  }
  i++;
}
res.push(tempArr);
console.log(res);
```